# Ubuntu 14.04 Low Graphics Error believe it is a mount error?

Tags: grub2, ati, fstab, crash

I rebooted my Ubuntu 14.04 from terminal 3 days ago and it seems to have undergone a catastrophic crash.

Firstly, I got a low graphics error issue.  I could not even get to the console, so I removed my graphics card.

After removing my graphics card, I noticed for some reason my smbd was not loading up, I could not log in even with the terminal.

So I created a new root account. Okay so back to the console, now I could log in, well kind of.  After logging in, it would always reboot back to the username login function.

So the only way it seems is to go to grub, recoverymode, enter thru root there, manually mount -o rw,remount / and try to look for errors.

Now I have uninstalled all my ATI drivers and am just using my onboard graphics card and have installed all the Intel drivers for it.  I don't believe this low graphics mode to be a graphics issue.

I tried looking at the xorg file, etc but I believe these errors are related to booting loadup issues.  I tried look at the dmesg | grep -i error and I just saw some ACPI errors.

So I tried to add in the option acpi=noacpi in the grub config and update-grub but then I got vgs and lvs invocation errors from grub-probe.

So basically.... I have no idea what I can do now.  Would appreciate help in narrowing down issues.  This is unusual since I have not had any problems for 6 months odd and have not added or removed anything new or substantial recently.  The most recent thing I installed before the crash was probably ClamAV but it booted fine multiple times since then.

EDIT:

So my bind9 is failing on start, which prob contributes it to not being able to connect to the LDAP server.  I am terrible with networking so I can't figure out why it is not working.  When I try to do service bind9 start it gives the 127.0.0.1#953 connection refused error.

Comment: If the worst comes to the worst I hope you've backed it up and you'll just have to reinstall :) sounds pretty stuffed up to me!